# Do DRIcore panels need to be flat?

Tags: basement, flooring, floor, subfloor

I want to install carpet tile over DRIcore on my concrete basement floor.  The floor is far from flat; I would guess at least an inch or two of overall variation.

Do I need to ensure the floor is flat for the DRIcore?  If so, how would I do this?  I see they make [integrated plastic shims](http://www.homedepot.com/p/DRIcore-5-in-Plastic-Shims-24-Pack-OLVKITUS000000/202086986), but they are apparently only designed to adjust the height by 1/4".

Comment: Boy, you are Mr. Famous Question aren't you?

Comment: @TylerDurden what do you mean?

Comment: 10% of your questions are famous questions, that is a pretty amazing percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion yes, you need to eliminate the dips. Anything that will be spanned over a low spot by the Dricore will move under foot. It is after all only a high grade OSB and the T&G joints will eventually fail somewhere over time.

The whole floor does not have to be level, just on the same plane.

On a concrete floor, a laser level will drive you crazy, do not do that to yourself. Technically, it needs to be flat, ideally it *should* be level, but level is not critical. I see eyes rolling now.... A string line will give you a good idea of what is in plane, not relying on it needing to be level. I refer to a level as a straight edge only, not using the bubble to determine level. Usually a level is always straight, therefore a good candidate for checking flatness over a given area. It is a lot of "hands and knees work". Scoot the level all over the floor to see how the floor plane is in any 4 ft span. This will help locate the high spots. Situate the level or straight edge over 2 high spots, anything over a 1/16" needs shimmed.

Comment: I wouldn't have to use a laser level or string? How can the four foot level work for a large area?

Comment: I added the comment to my answer above.

Comment: Thanks, accepted; also edited my question to "flat" rather than level.  I never actually thought it needed to be literally level, only free of dips.

Answer (score 0):

The DRIcore website says:

> Any dips or low spots in the concrete surface greater than 1/4" should
>   be trowelled level with a Portland cement compound or leveled with a
>   self-leveling compound to ensure an accurate installation.

I'm still not sure whether or not it's necessary with carpet tiles though.